# Get the latest version release field from a JSON response

Tags: json, jq

I want to automatically download latest LTS for AdoptiumJDK. So I found [a good list](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coursier/jvm-index/master/index.json) to start with.

I want to filter only stable Releases for 1.17, so I tried:

```bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coursier/jvm-index/master/index.json 
| jq -r '.linux.amd64."jdk@adoptium-jre" 
| to_entries[] 
| .[] 
| select(match("1.17.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$"))'
```

gives:

> ```
> 1.17.0.1
> 1.17.0.2
> 1.17.0.3
> 1.17.0.4
> ```

but I want the latest (highest number) release, and I want the URL of this release.

```bash
curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coursier/jvm-index/master/index.json 
| jq -r '.linux.amd64."jdk@adoptium-jre" 
| to_entries[] 
| .[] 
| select(match("1.17.[0-9]+.[0-9]+$"))'   
| sort -n 
| tail -1
```

but thats not elegant, I have to parse this output via bash and do a new lookup.

How can I get the URL for the current newest release for 1.17 (should give `"tgz+https://github.com/adoptium/temurin17-binaries/releases/download/jdk-17.0.4%2B8/OpenJDK17U-jre_x64_linux_hotspot_17.0.4_8.tar.gz"`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of getting the version fields alone, you could get the key/value pair as part of applying the regex and then do a `sort_by` on the version field. Remember to escape the `.` character to be treated as a literal, or use `startswith("1.17.")`

```bash
.linux.amd64."jdk@adoptium-jre" 
| to_entries 
| map(select(.key | test("1\\.17\\.[0-9]+\\.[0-9]+$"))) 
| sort_by(.key | split(".") | map(tonumber)) 
| last.value
```

The key part here is the `sort_by` expression that tells `jq` to split the version field to constituent strings and then convert to numbers, i.e. `map(tonumber)` and then perform sort operation on it.

With the operation, the list `[1, 17, 0, 4]` is expected to be the highest among the rest of the records. The `last` builtin picks up the last record in a list of elements.

jqplay [demo](https://jqplay.org/s/HtdJhy4tnWa)

Answer (score 2):

Give `max_by` a try.

```bash
.linux.amd64."jdk@adoptium-jre"
| to_entries
| map(select(.key | startswith("1.17.")))
| max_by(.key)
| .value
```